# How to break Visual Studio 2010 JavaScript debugger from script

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2010

Is there a JavaScript command that will cause the Visual Studio 2010 debugger to break?

Trying `break();` didn't work because it's only valid within loops. Also `stop();` failed because it picked up that `stop()` doesn't exist and I didn't have a useful stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript has a [`debugger`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.15) statement, it woks in firebug, so it should in VS 2010 as well.

> **12.15   The debugger statement**
>
> Evaluating the DebuggerStatement
>   production may allow an implementation
>   to cause a breakpoint when run under a
>   debugger. If a debugger is not present
>   or active this statement has no
>   observable effect.
>
> *ECMA-262 5th Edition*